# Downcasting a borrowed box

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The [`downcast()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) method of Rust's `Box` type requires the call site to have full ownership of the Box instance. There doesn't appear to be an equivalent that can work with a borrowed reference. Is there a reason for this? Is there a workaround that will work on a borrowed instance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an alternative, but it's not a method of `Box`: it's [`Any::downcast_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_ref). Thanks to deref coersion and `Box`es `Deref`-impl, you can call `T`'s methods on a `Box<T>` directly. Thus you can call `Any::downcast_ref()` on your `Box<Any>` directly:

```
let b: Box<Any> = Box::new(27u64);

// The type of `ref_a` and `ref_b` is `&u64`
let ref_a = b.downcast_ref::<u64>().unwrap();
let ref_b = b.downcast_ref::<u64>().unwrap();
println!("{} == {}", ref_a, ref_b);
```

There is also [`Any::downcast_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast_mut) to obtain a mutable reference.

Comment: This was a perfect answer. And SO even figured out the question I was about to pose was answered here six years ago. This should have made it into the rust Box documentation by now.